# Why can I no longer run unit tests from Resharper's test runner?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

Things were running fine.  Who knows what changed, but now I end up with:

Unit Test Runner failed to load test assembly:
JetBrains.Resharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TaskException:Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CommandLine.CommandLineParameterException' was thrown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Who knows what changed? Your version control :)   Hopefully....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just been having the same problem. It turned out that the Solution Items "folder" had a couple of .testsettings files in it which didn't actually exist (probably because they weren't added to the Git repo). Anyway, I removed them from the Solution and the R# runner now works fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had just fixed it as well, I forgot to update this post.  I was missing my local.testsettings file.  In solution items, I added a new item of that type, and poof, R# runner working again.  Thx!

Comment: I closed the solution and used SVN clean with the options:
[x] delete unversioned files and folders.
[x] delete ignored files and folders.
When restarting Studio everything was working again.
Be careful to not loose data if you use this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP?q=JetBrains.Resharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TaskException) for R# bugs that have the same description and maybe find the cause of your problem or a possible workaround. [This bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-181806) seems to come close.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me unfortunately, instead I had to create a testsettings file manually to resolve the issue:

Right click Solution root

- Add > New Item...
- Select Test Settings from the Installed Templates column
- Select the Test Settings item, and rename to the desired file name as necessary
- Add

You should now be able to run your unit tests correctly.